# Typified DataTable to get her row values using a custom class

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I'm been looking some way to use DataTables and get values of her rows using a custom class.

My approach is the following:

```
DataTable dtUsers = new DataTable();

dtUsers.Columns.Add("Name");
dtUsers.Columns.Add("Last name");
dtUsers.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

for (int x = 1; x <= 100; x++)
{
    dtUsers.Rows.Add(new object[]
    {
        "Name " + x,
        "Last name " + x,
        x
    });
}

// I want to do this
var Name = dtUsers.Rows[0].Name; // Get "Name 1"
var Age = dtUsers.Rows[50].Age; // Get "Age 50"

// Or
foreach(DataRow drCurrent in dtUsers.Select("Age > 50"))
{
    int Age = drCurrent.Age; // Get 51,52,53..
}
```

I'm thinking something like this:

```
public class DataTablePerson : DataTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // Implement a method to return a specific value in some specific row
    public string Last_name { get; set; } // Implement a method to return a specific value in some specific row
    public int Age { get; set; }// Implement a method to return a specific value in some specific row
}
```

Exists a method to achieve this?

Will be double of useful if I could use the custom class using as parameter some Typified class, to reapply this class other structures (Ex: Person, Tree, Movie, Book).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Err no, don't use array-based data model for your application. [I have blogged it why](http://serlock-works.blogspot.com/2015/03/code-smell-array-based-data-model.html). Instead, convert the data table to `List`/`Array`/`Enumerable` of your own class model (POCO) and use it instead.

But if you insist to use it (it's your own choice though), you can do it with "wrapper class".

```
public class DataTablePerson{
    public DataTablePerson(DataTable source){
        this.Source = source;
    }
    protected DataTable Source = null;

    public string Name(int row = 0){
        return Get("name", row);
    }
    public string LastName(int row = 0){
        return Get("last_name", row);
    }
    public int Age(int row = 0){
        return Convert.ToInt32(Get("age", row));
    }

    protected string Get(string name, int row){
        return source.Rows[row][name].ToString();
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
DataTablePerson dtp = new DataTablePerson(dtUsers);
string name = dtp.Name(1);
```

Or if you want row-level entity (you can use property in exchange though):

```
public class DataRowPerson{
    public DataRowPerson(DataRow source){
        this.Source = source;
    }
    protected DataRow Source = null;

    public string Name(){
        return source["name"].ToString();
    }
    public string LastName(){
        return source["last_name"].ToString();
    }
    public int Age(){
        return Convert.ToInt32(source["age"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
foreach(DataRow drCurrent in dtUsers.Select("Age > 50"))
{
    DataRowPerson drp = new DataRowPerson(drCurrent);
    int Age = drp.Age; // Get 51,52,53..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it! Only instead of using property notation, you just need to specify the column name as a string inside square brackets:

```
var Name = dtUsers.Rows[0]["Name"];
var Age = dtUsers.Rows[50]["Age"];
```

Or:

```
var agesOverFifty = new List<int>();
foreach (DataRow currentRow in dtUsers.Select("Age > 50"))
{
    agesOverFifty.Add(Convert.ToInt32(currentRow["Age"]));
}
```

Or even using LINQ:

```
List<int> agesOverFifty = dtUsers.Select("Age > 50")
    .Select(row => Convert.ToInt32(row["Age"]))
    .ToList();

Console.WriteLine("The average age of a person over 50 in our sample is: {0}",
    agesOverFifty.Average());
```

Comment: Thanks, but; 1) This is the normal method (I want know the existing columns in the source). 2 and 3) I will have a values of a specific column; I want have all values of the DataRow.